# Aframe super-hands component: not getting disabled

Tags: aframe, aframe-super-hands

I am testing the `super-hands` component (https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component) to move an object. For the same I am setting the `grabbable` gesture component. What I am noticing is that once I have moved the object I am unable to "shake-off" the moving viz. it continues to be in a state of grabbable. The code is simple

`<a-box ... grabbable></a-box>
..
<a-entity raycaster="objects: .clickable" cursor="rayOrigin:mouse" super-hands="colliderEvent: raycaster-intersection; colliderEventProperty: els; colliderEndEvent: raycaster-intersection-cleared; colliderEndEventProperty: el"></a-entity>`

Does something need to be set to disable the grabbable state?

Comment: How well does super-hands work with a `rayOrigin: mouse`? Message Will Murphy and he can help out maybe.

Comment: The object moves left and right in the manner desired. The ultimate objective being that I would like the movement to be restricted for which I will possibly create a component that will let the x and z coordinates be within the specified area. And yes, will connect with Murphy. Thanks @ngokevin